# Is concurrent script execution possible in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to analyze some data in a table that was run after an update and have no idea how this is possible, so I wanted to ask the community if there is any plausible way this could have happened.

There is a script that is similar to:

```
Delete Table abc
insert into abc(value) VALUES 'def'
```

We are looking at the database and this data now exists:

```
id   value
---  -----
1     def
2     def
```

I can't think of a possible way this could have occurred, other than the script being run concurrently from separate instances, but just can't see how this could have occurred (other than manual entry, but apparently this could not have happened)

Does anyone know if this is even possible and if so how?  Also, if there are any suggestions to avoid this possibility?

Comment: Queries should be executed in order. How big is the table? what happen if you use TRUNCATE instead of DELETE?

Comment: Thanks Yuriy, I won't be able to run it again since it's in production, but the admin may have automated it to run concurrently from separate machines (although I still don't think this is possible).  I wonder if the script was wrapped in a tran...

Comment: If your two statements are not being run in an explicit transaction block, then each one is running is an implicit, separate transaction.  It's certainly possible for a race condition to occur such that the system executes two connections as `delete`, `delete`, `insert`,`insert`.